# How to count the number of output tuples in cascading

Tags: hadoop, cascading

Using cascading framework, I am filtering some tuples and outputting those in an S3 file.

I also want to count the number of output total tuples. One simple way is to download the output S3 file and count the number of lines.

Is there any other way to dump the count of output tuples to another file?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a [flowprocess](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.0/javadoc/cascading/flow/FlowProcess.html).

We can write a custom function.

```
public class Counter extends BaseOperation implements Function {
  ...
  @Override
  public void operate(FlowProcess flowProcess, FunctionCall functionCall) {
    functionCall.getOutputCollector().add(functionCall.getArguments());
    flowProcess.increment(counterGroup, counterName, 1);
  }
...
}
```

Use :

groupByPipe = new Each(groupByPipe, new Counter(COUNTER_GROUP_NAME, counterName));